# Should check for duplicate or catch exception from database?

Tags: database, algorithm

When we program with database (for example in Java and MySql), should we check for duplicate entry before inserting, or should we just insert and catch the duplicate exception to raise alert to users ?

In my opinion, if we do the check, and if there is no duplicate entry, we insert the entry, and the database engine itself checks for duplicate primary key again. It sounds a waste of time.

How do you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For you to check client side(in your program) if there is a duplicate key, it would require querying the database. Since the insert query will return an error if there is already a record existing with the same PK, it is not necessary to perform this check before the insert statement is sent. 
You can insert, catch the exception/error code (i'm not sure if it will give an exception in java, or return an error code) and then alert the user.

EDIT - 
If there are many users using the same database, the main issue if you check and then insert will be that someone else can insert the same key after you checked but before you insert. IF you would like to do it this way, you would need to use transactions - the check and insert must both happen in the same transaction. You can read up on MySQL transactions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html).

Comment: That's also what I think! Tks!

Comment: This is only the right answer by accident.  The *main* problem with check-then-insert is a race condition: someone else can insert the same key *after* you checked but *before* you insert.  For check-then-insert to be reliable, the check and insert must both happen in the same transaction, but you didn't mention transactions at all.  -1 until you fix this.

Comment: @j_random_hacker : Thank you for your input. :) I have modified my answer as advised. I had not (evidently) though about transactions when i answered this.

Answer (score 5):

Wasting time isn't your biggest concern.

I'm assuming more than one user (or process) can access your database at any one time; if you rely purely on a "pre-insert" check, it's possible for a different user to change the state of the database (e.g. insert a record with the ID that you're trying to insert) in the time between your check and your insert statement.

Thus, you should always handle "duplicate key" errors in a user friendly way.

However, current user interfaces seem to do both - validate data before submitting it to the database, *and* handle data integrity errors nicely.

There are several reasons for doing this - user friendliness for one, but efficiency and performance are also a big deal. In most applications, the database is a "scarce resource", and relying on errors for application logic is expensive and inefficient.

So, if you're only inserting a single record into a single table, using the "duplicate key" exception is fine. If you're inserting multiple records, into multiple tables, with foreign keys etc. and (hopefully) a transaction or two, using the exception is expensive and may create a lot of "roll back" effort.

On MySQL, this is exacerbated by the varying support for transactions (depending on which version and storage option you use).